# Unity Zoom script

Tags: unity-game-engine, zooming

I use this simple zoom script, changing the cameras Field of View instead of moving the camera (to avoid clipping) and it works great.

However I would like to add a maximum FOV to it, like FOV 80 or so.
Maybe also a Minimum FOV (not as important as max FOV)?

Can I do that modifying this script?

```
 {
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
     {
         GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView--;
     }
     if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
     {
         GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView++;
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the desired min and max values as members to your script. Then you can use the inspector to adjust them:

```
private Camera cam;
[SerializeField] private float minFov = 20;
[SerializeField] private float maxFov = 80;

void Awake()
{
    cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    // ensures that the field of view is within min and max on startup
    UpdateFov(cam.fieldOfView);
}

void Update()
{
    float scrollInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    if(scrollInput > 0)
        UpdateFov(cam.fieldOfView - 1);
    else if(scrollInput < 0)
        UpdateFov(cam.fieldOfView + 1);    
}

void UpdateFov(float newFov)
{
    cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(newFov, minFov, maxFov);
}
```

I also cached the camera, since `GetComponent` calls are rather expensive.

Comment: Exactly what i was hoping to achieve.
Thank you, again Thomas :)

Are you schooled in C#?
Or did you learn by yourself?
If you dont mind me asking?

I find the learning curve to be pretty steep.

Comment: I learned it myself. There are pretty good books and articles out there.